# How to host Laravel 5.8 Application in my domain (domain.com)?

Tags: php, laravel

I have tried to host my **Laravel 5.8** based application on my domain (domain.com/xyz) as similar to the Laravel based project written on the previous version (keep everything on root path and keep the *public* folder in *public_html*, but it does not work.

For example, my folder is xyz in the root directory. *index.php* file still searching that directory in the **../public_html/xyz** rather than **home/my_website/xyz**

Here is my code:

`require __DIR__.'/../xyz/vendor/autoload.php';`

`$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../xyz/bootstrap/app.php';`

Answer (score 1):

- Create a folder, XYZ in your root of `public_html`.
- Move the contents of your app to to xyz folder.
- Mover `index.php` and `.htacces` file from `public` folder to
  `public_html\xyz` folder.
- Modify `index.php` like this

  `require __DIR__.'vendor/autoload.php';`

  `$app = require_once __DIR__.'bootstrap/app.php';`

And if your css and js stops working add `{{asset('public')}}/` before your imports, for example

```
<link href="{{ asset('public') }}/demo/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="{{ asset('public') }}/js/core/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then you can access your website at http://example.com/xyz

Comment: https://bytesoft.tinytake.com/tt/MzU2MjE0NV8xMDc0MTE2MQ

Will the problem (in the link) solved by that?

Comment: @Shimul, yes, just modify the index.php like i have mentioned in the answer, you can directly copy it.

Comment: Rest of the content except **app** folder will be in **public_html/xyz** folder [moving index.php and .htaccess from xyz/public to xyz]?

Comment: @shimul Yeah. you should do that if you don't want `example.com/xyz/public/` everytime you visit the site