# Laravel - Remove public/index.php from URL

Tags: php, laravel

Dears,

I''m new in Laravel, and am doing a personal project.
I have a website (HTML/CSS) and inside the website, a menu in order to start using the web application (Laravel 5.5 and php7.1).

I uploaded my codes to the server (ubuntu 16.04 Droplet) but i'm not able to access the website without putting public/index.php

for example, am using the guards (admin and users), so in order to go to admin page: `www.mydomain/admin` and for user `www.mydomain/user`.

But am not able to access this

> (500 ERROR) and when i put  www.mydomain/public/index.php/admin it
>   works, even www.mydomain/public/admin is not working.

**public/.htaccess:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} . 
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

default-ssl.conf (using keys and https)

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                ServerAdmin info@ecollectionz.com
ServerName ecollectionz.com
ServerAlias www.ecollectionz.com

                DocumentRoot /var/www/html

                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/private/ef125a55e77fd883.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/private-key.key
 <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>
...
```

Pleae note that am using the website and the web app on same domain, so the index home page (/var/www/html) is for the website
Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Do you have the mod_rewrite enabled? Anyway maybe you should start by configuring the server well so that the path "index.php" does not have to be called through yourserver.com/public/. You can check the creation of "Virtual Hosts" in the documentation of your server

Comment: Yes enabled dear, Actually i have a website and the app on same domain, so the index home page is for the website (/var/www/html)

Comment: Please show us your .htaccess config and/or your VH config file.

Comment: But no here! edit your post ^^

Comment: @MohammadKassab https://stackoverflow.com/a/56421681/9622918

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use this code for your .htaccess https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation#web-server-configuration also make sure to enable the mod_rewrite module in your apache

Comment: Actually i had a website and the web application, i tried to put the code from your link in public/.htaccess bt it doesnt work!

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind to pay 19$/month i advise you to use [Laravel Forge](https://forge.laravel.com/). You can deploy unlimited Laravel apps (and other php apps) with 0 configuration.